# echofunc showing too many function declearations

Tags: c++, vim, ctags

I'm new to write cpp in vim and I find the vim plugin is showing too many function definitions.

Like when it comes to a `std::string x.find()`, the [`echofunc`](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1735) will give a lot of functions declarations (as many as 142 declarations) including those like `find(const key_type& __key)` in `/usr/include/c++/4.4.3/backward/hashtable.h`.

I mean, I just need it showing the parameters of `std::string.find()`, why it goes so wrong?

BTW, I generated the ctags in a way like

```
ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+liaS --extra+=q /usr/include /usr/local/include
```

Comment: on the other hand, the omnicppcomplete plugin is working fine with this ctags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a lot of headers include function declarations called 'find' under /usr/include or /usr/local/include. I don't know how ominicppcomplete works fine but as its name implies it may did some optimization for cplusplus. However 'echofund' didn't, its only optimized for c. Try to limit headers to libstdc++ and re-generate tags to see if that could solve your problem.